# How can I convert a RACDisposable to a Disposable in ReactiveCocoa 5?

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-cocoa, reactive-cocoa-4, reactive-cocoa-5

In ReactiveCocoa 5, how can I convert a `RACDisposable` to a `Disposable`? If I try to add a `RACDisposable` to a `CompositeDisposable`, I get "Binary operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'CompositeDisposable' and 'RACDisposable'".

Answer (score 0):

Use a closure to wrap the Objective-C things.

```
let disposable = CompositeDisposable()

let racDisposable = RACDisposable()

disposable += {
    racDisposable.dispose()
}
```